# Module 'SquareReaderSDK' not found 'react-native-square-reader-sdk ' in react native

Tags: xcode, react-native, square

native-square-reader-sdk** for payments in my project.

> iOS build is failing due to "Module 'SquareReaderSDK' not found"
>
> package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-camera-kit": "^8.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-globalize": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-square-reader-sdk": "1.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-native-webview": "7.0.5",
    "react-native-star-prnt": "1.1.0",
    "base-64": "0.1.0"
  },
```

how to solve this ?

thanks

Comment: Did you follow the Reader SDK iOS installation steps including the build phase? https://github.com/square/react-native-square-reader-sdk/blob/master/docs/get-started.md#step-5-install-reader-sdk-for-ios

Comment: thanks    i have followed it and it worked correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow the following steps to install **SquareReaderSDK**

[Steps for SquareSDK Installation](https://github.com/SudoPlz/react-native-sp-reader-sdk/wiki/Step-2:-iOS-Setup)